# File System Task failing to move ZIP files in SSIS 2005

Tags: ssis

Before we start: Yes, I have to use 2005. No, I can't upgrade, it's not my decision.

I have an SSIS package that is suppsed to perform the following tasks:
1. Zip a text file using 7-zip
2. FTP the file to a specified site
3. Move the zipped file to an archive folder

Steps 1 and 2 work fine, but when it comes time to move the folder it fails. The error message says, "Could not find a part of the path '\Shares2\clntrial\DataMgt\C1460\DataTransfer\Data\Sent\TXT\archive\ABC701_XXX_2015-09-30.zip\ABC701_XXX_2015-09-30.zip'."  As you can see, it has the zip file name in the path twice.

That file destination path is set by a connection manager with the connection string populated by an expression that uses variables. When I edit the expression, it evaluates to the correct path with the file name appearing only once, that is, "\Shares2\clntrial\DataMgt\C1460\DataTransfer\Data\Sent\TXT\archive\ABC701_XXX_2015-09-30.zip".

Why is SSIS adding the file name a second time when the package runs?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I'm an idiot. By including the zip file name "ABC701_XXX_2015-09-30.zip" in the destination I'm telling the file system task to consider that the target folder. Duh.